# What does "have no serious doubts about..." mean?

Tags: meaning

Does it mean to have "reasonable doubts", or "no doubt at all", or "a little bit doubt"?

Comment: It means **significant** doubts. There might be aspects about which you have doubts, but are unimportant. For example when considering a job offer, you might have serious doubts because of the commuting involved, but minor doubts about the dress code.

Comment: It means just as it says -- no serious doubts means that there is a lack of serious doubts. Depending on the inflection of the speaker, it could mean that he/she has minor doubts or no doubts at all. In any case, a lack of something serious usually means the person is proceeding with the decision or does not think negatively about the person involved.